# Call AJAX client side with request server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have `.ejs` file with `HTML` and `AJAX`.
I want execute only `if` the condition inside app.js file it's true.

I debug the `if` inside `app.js` with `console.log('works')` and works fine.

**My .ejs file:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

    // .......... etc etc...........
<script>
//function with ajax
function login(usr, pss, numberOrigin){
       
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/login',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "userName":usr,
    "password":pss
    }),
  success:function(output) {
  //  console.log(output.sessionID);
    getData(output.sessionID, numberOrigin);
  },
  error:function(output) {
     }
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My app.js file:**
Obs.: In this case the `updateMessage` is called after the login of the API via `POST` with `express`. I am integrating, and my if is a context variable that will be manipulated, and my app.js recognizes this variable, which in the case is response.data (I have already tested).

```
app.post( '/api/xx', function(req, res) {
  var idData= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxae";  
  if ( !idData|| idData=== '<idData>' ) {
    return res.json( {
      'output': {
        'text': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    } );
  }
  var payload = {
    idData: idData,
    context: {},
    input: {}
  };
  if ( req.body ) {
    if ( req.body.input ) {
      payload.input = req.body.input;
    }
    if ( req.body.context ) {
      // The client must maintain context/state
      payload.context = req.body.context;
    }
  }
  // Send the input to the service
  api.message( payload, function(err, data) {
    if ( err ) {
      return res.status( err.code || 500 ).json( err );
    }
    updateMessage( res, payload, data );
  } );
} );


function updateMessage(res, input, response) {
  if (response.data!= 'undefined') {
  //console.log('it works');
    login();; //and after getData it's invokes
  }
```

**My repository:**

Obs.: Public folder have `.ejs` file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtAJ1.jpg)

I'm sorry if I try something wrong, but if yes, please let me know how to solved this or another way to solve.

Thanks advance

Comment: I don't follow, from where `updateMessage(x,x,x)` is called?

Comment: In this case the updateMessage is called after the login of the API via POST that I am integrating, and my if is a context variable that will be manipulated, and my app.js recognizes this variable, which in the case is response.data (I have already tested). I'm sorry i dont inform it inside post, I will edit

Comment: And who invoques `login()`?

Comment: after login getData it's invoques